# Corda: How/where can I try to configure database connection retries

Tags: corda

Is it possible to configure database connection retry in Corda?

I see in Corda docs we can use `dataSourceProperties` for `maximumPoolSize` and `connectionTimeout` but is there any `retry` property or is there a default?

Or maybe it’s the `connectionTimeout` that the node uses to keep trying until the database is available again (given a scenario where the database was unavailable for a brief period).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current moment, the Corda node should exit if the pool can't reconnect.

It behaves this way to prevent the persisted states and the in-memory states diverge, which may result in the break of provenance.

Yet, this discussion is continued for scenarios like database maintenance and backup.